# C# substring out of range

Tags: c#, substring

The problem I am having is that I need to be able to loop over a string, returning 5 characters after the position of the index, then starting 5 characters after.

However when there are less than 5 characters left an out of range error occurs, I thought it would just print the remaining characters of the string.

```
string string1 = "ghuitghtruighr";
for (int index = 0; index < string1.Length; index += 5)
{
    string subString = string1.Substring(i, 5);
    Console.WriteLine(subString);
}
```

How can I get it to print what's left of the string when whats remaining is less than 5?

Comment: [Per the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) it will throw an exception when `length indicates a position not within this instance.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `Substring()` from the index to the end of the string and then check whether the resulting substring contains more than 5 characters:

```
string string1 = "ghuitghtruighr";
for (int index = 0; index < string1.Length; index += 5)
{
    string subString = string1.Substring(index);
    if(subString.Length > 5)
        subString = subString.Substring(0, 5);
    Console.WriteLine(subString);
}
```

---

Don't do the above if you have many distinct strings of great length - `string`s are immutable so calling `Substring()` twice on every iteration results in an extra string on the heap every time - rather [calculate the difference between Length and index like suggested by Xerillio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35281629/712649)

Answer (score 8):

You could use the LINQ `.Skip(...)` & `.Take(...)` operators like so:

```
for (int index = 0; index < string1.Length; index += 5)
{
    string subString = new String(string1.Skip(index).Take(5).ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine(subString);
}
```

That gives:

```
ghuit
ghtru
ighr
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace line 3 of OP code with this:

`string subString = string1.Substring(i, string1.Length - i < 5 ? string1.Length - i : 5);`

Comment: While correct, your answer needs some explanatory text.  Why does it work?  What problem does it solve?  What is the cause of that problem?  Single-line code-only answers are opaque.